# Use OS environment variables to apache2 ports conf

Tags: apache2, apache2.4

is there a way to use OS environment variables to apache2 ports conf? tried

**ports.conf**

```
Listen 80
Listen {$CUSTOM_PORT1}
```

in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` but unfortunately it returns invalid config.

Any idea, help, suggestions, recommendations is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.